# Is it possible to define packages within sbt's project directory

Tags: sbt

I defined some classes in sbt's `project` directory using no package (i.e. all my files were directly under `project` and they did not include any package statement). It worked fine.

Now when I tried to group them into packages and ran `sbt reload` I got `not found: value XXX` at the line I imported the package in my `build.sbt` (`XXX` is the name of the package).

Can't `project` deal with packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after comment

It will work if you add your source files in folder `project/src/main/scala`

Check this structure

```
tree
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    └── src
        └── main
            └── scala
                └── foo
                    └── Bar.scala

5 directories, 3 files
```

build.sbt

```
import foo._

version := Bar.ver
```

and Bar.scala

```
package foo

object Bar {
  val ver  = "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still does not work if I put my source files in sub-directories matching the packages: `xxx is not a member of package <root>`.
It is as if sbt was ignoring any directory in `project` and only cared about files.

Comment: @stackoverflowed you are absolutely correct. I did not fully tested it. Please find updated answer.